# Vue- async function returns Promise {<pending>}

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Okay so this is some basic Vue that I'm having difficulties with:

I'm trying to fetch some data (anime) from an anime API which was available online

I have Anime.vue (which is the view page) and getAnime.js (which contains the function). When I had the function in the Anime.vue file it worked but I tried to separate it and now I can't send the anime the vue page. Here's the code:

Anime.vue (only included the script part)

```
<script>
import getAnime from "../composables/getAnime";
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  setup() {
    let anime = getAnime();

    console.log(anime); //this returns Promise pending on console
  },
};
</script>
```

and this getAnime.js file:

```
async function getAnime() {
  const axios = require("axios");
  let anime = ''

  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/" + 20)
    .then((res) => {          
        anime = res.data
        console.log(anime) //this returns the anime file as {request hash...
       })
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return anime
}
export default getAnime
```

Comment: you are mixing both promise and async await. try async-await just remove  .then

Comment: and your also need `async setup() { let anime = await getAnime();` when you use it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
async function getAnime() {
  const axios = require("axios");

  try {
     const response = await axios.get("https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/" + 20);
     return response;
  } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
  }
}
export default getAnime
```

Comment: this should work or you can use .then where you are assigning it to variable like  getAnime().then(result => {let anime = result})

Comment: How does this solve a problem? `anime` is still a promise.

Answer (score 0):

`async` function returns a Promise implicitly, so you need to `await` the result.

```
async function getAnime() {
  const axios = require("axios");

  try {
     const response = await axios.get("https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/" + 20);
     return response;
  } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
     throw error;  
  }
}
export default getAnime;
```

In your vue file :

```
try {
  const animeData = await getAnime();
} catch(e) {
 // handle errors
}
```

Comment: The answer doesn't show how this applies to Vue part, which is obviously the problem in the OP.

Comment: @EstusFlask I think I've shown how to handle the vue part. Is there something specific that you want to highlight?